# EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE 6985 Response

Tags: android, nfc, smartcard, apdu

I'm working on EXTERNAL AUTHENTICATE for IDs and passports according to ICAO 9303.

Firstly I selected app.

```
(byte) 0x00, // CLA Class
(byte) 0xA4, // INS Instruction
(byte) 0x04, // P1  Parameter 1
(byte) 0x0C, // P2  Parameter 2
(byte) 0x07, // length
(byte) 0xA0,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x00,(byte) 0x02,(byte) 0x47,(byte) 0x10,(byte) 0x01 //AID
RESPONSE = 90 00
```

Then I sent CHALLENGE command

```
(byte) 0x00, // CLA Class
(byte) 0x84, // INS Instruction
(byte) 0x00, // P1  Parameter 1
(byte) 0x00, // P2  Parameter 2
(byte) 0x08 // request 8 byte
RESPONSE = 2E 50 58 B1 D9 EB 7B B1 90 00
```

Finally after some calculations, I sent E.IFD||M.IFD

```
//everything is hex
00  // CLA Class
82  // INS Instruction
00  // P1  Parameter 1
00  // P2  Parameter 2
28 // data sent length
E2 5F 2A A2 92 35 A3 83 32 8F FF 37 82 98 23 4B 33 BE B9 96 32 36 E1 48 CC 88 8F 05 87 8B 36 C3 DA 59 D1 84 91 A7 09 4C //  KEY_E_IFD_M_IFD
28 // length expected 
RESPONSE= 69 85
```

I controlled my cryptographic functions with the example in the ICAO 9303. Everthing seems OK. But I can not understand why I got 6985 response. These are my calculations:

```
RAND.IFD = 5F 48 F0 2F 61 30 B7 60
K.IFD = 97 68 E5 8D DE A8 A8 EF 51 3D D9 00 BB 2F 19 42
K.SEED = 80 EB 6E 08 3F BC BB 75 F2 5B A5 EB 34 0E 0D 52
RND_IC = 2E 50 58 B1 D9 EB 7B B1
S = 5F 48 F0 2F 61 30 B7 60 2E 50 58 B1 D9 EB 7B B1 97 68 E5 8D DE A8 A8 EF 51 3D D9 00 BB 2F 19 42
K_ENC: 9D 80 C1 38 E5 61 6D 58 A1 94 CE CD B5 85 19 AD
K_MAC: 86 52 46 D9 E0 2F 4F F1 C7 15 8F 54 C1 F1 38 46
E_IFD: E2 5F 2A A2 92 35 A3 83 32 8F FF 37 82 98 23 4B 33 BE B9 96 32 36 E1 48 CC 88 8F 05 87 8B 36 C3
M_IFD: DA 59 D1 84 91 A7 09 4C
KEY_E_IFD_M_IFD: E2 5F 2A A2 92 35 A3 83 32 8F FF 37 82 98 23 4B 33 BE B9 96 32 36 E1 48 CC 88 8F 05 87 8B 36 C3 DA 59 D1 84 91 A7 09 4C
```

Thank you

Comment: Your cryptography looks indeed correct (if KSeed wasn't the correct hash of your MRZ I'd have expected to see a 6300 instead). Have you checked that your passport sample indeed supports BAC? The current part 11 of ICAO 9303 states that PACE only is a valid configuration starting from 01.2018 for MRTD.

Comment: @Ale Thank you for your support. Magically, today commands are working correctly without changing any code (I controlled with VCS) except that first time im getting 69 85 then in other tries program is working correctly. I have really no idea what causes this stability issues. Apparently, some IDs still support BAC in addition PACE.

Comment: Sporadic effects like that usually hint at someone not being able to handle sth like leading zero byte(s) that are part of a hash code like K.Seed or decryption unintentionally misinterpreting trailing zero byte(s) as part of the padding string...